# Pandas: Seperate a row of strings into 4 columns; Problem: the columns are seperated by comma, tab and space

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file and I'm trying to separate the entries of a row to a new column. One row looks like this :

> 12:00, Info "here are 18 spaces" ABC    some text<

I started like this

```
table = pd.read_table(file, 
                  sep=',',
                  names=['Time', 'ID'])
```

And now I have a Dataframe with 2 columns: Time and ID
But how can I separate the "ID" column? Especially when the entries are separated by tab and space.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly is your wanted outcome?

"table.ID.str.split(expand=True)" will split into its elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern to precisely define the rules for splitting your string row:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "A": [
        "12:00, Info    ABC some text\tmoretext"
    ]
})

# split on comma followed by a space OR 1+ whitespace (inc. tab) character 
df.A.str.split(r", |\s+", expand=True)

       0     1    2     3     4         5
0  12:00  Info  ABC  some  text  moretext
```